# Why do the xi:include lookups 'fail' in command line XSLT processing?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, tei

I generally use Oxygen to test my single-file transformations XML -> HTML. (The XML files use the TEI schema.) I use a lot of `xi:includes` to reference lists of people `<listPerson/>` and places `<listPlace/>` in my markup using @xml:id.

I do the lookups in the `xi:include` using the `@xml:id` in a key like this:

```
<xsl:key name="persnymRef" match="tei:listPerson/tei:person" use="@xml:id"/>
```

Using code like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select = "key('persnymRef',$get_persNam)/tei:persName,' ')"/>
```

So, `@xml:id="petrus_fabri_PAR"` returns the value `Peire Faure, Paris` from the file `<xi:include href="people.xml">`. The xml file is in the same directory as the other files.

When I use Oxygen to do the transformation, everything outputs fine.

But I am now testing command line processing using Saxon and any lookup depending on an `xl:include` fails (ie. outputs nothing for the xml:id lookup) - the rest of the XSLT file processing works fine.

Why do the `xi:include` lookups 'fail' in command line?

Is there a special consideration for using `xi:include` in command line processing of XML using XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to turn the xi:include processing explicitly **on** in Saxon. Maybe this page will help you: https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/sourcedocs/XInclude.html